# Add attributes to an instance using strong params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The prime example of this feature is when creating a user. Instead of saving 'password' to the database you want to take an instance's `password` and create a `password_hash` and `password_salt` from it.

So if I'm creating a form where a user can be created, how can I have a password field if there's no 'password' attribute?

I think previously this could be solved by using `attr_accessor` in the user model, but I don't know how to do this with strong params:

```
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

Just results in a UnknownAttributes error when trying to create a new instance via the user_params:

```
@user = User.new(user_params)
```

Comment: it should be `User.new(params[:user])` or `User.new(params)` right ?

Comment: @shiva, for Rails 4.0+, you need to use Strong Params (the syntax is correct here)

Comment: ok, i've just referred this doc https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add to your strong params, you can use the [`.merge`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge) method

```
private
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:x, :y, :z).merge(hair_color: "brown")
end
```

Alternatively, if you're looking to manipulate the data on save, you'd probably use the [ActiveRecord callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html), namely `before_create`:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_create :hash_password

    private

    def hash_password
        if password #-> == self.password
             #hash the password
             #runs after validations
             #runs just before DB insert
        end
    end

end
```